# NLTK StanfordPOSTagger not working - Windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, nltk, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

OS:Windows 10 x64

Python: 2.7.3

NLTK: 3.1

I want to use [Stanford Pos tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) in python so based on documentation in [here](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#module-nltk.tag.stanford), I did these:

I've downloaded `stanford-postagger-2015-04-20.zip` from [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) and extract it to `D:\Downloads\stanford-postagger-2015-04-20\stanford-postagger-2015-04-20`

[image: contents of stanford-postagger-2015-04-20]
[image]

I've created two environment variables:

```
CLASSPATH >>> D:\Downloads\stanford-postagger-2015-04-20\stanford-postagger-2015-04-20\stanford-postagger.jar
STANFORD_MODELS >>> D:\Downloads\stanford-postagger-2015-04-20\stanford-postagger-2015-04-20\models\
```

Using this code to use the tagger:

```
import os
java_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin/java.exe"
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path

from nltk.tag import StanfordPOSTagger

st = StanfordPOSTagger('english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger')

st.tag('What is the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?'.split())
```

raises this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: edu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/MaxentTagger : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Exception in thread "main" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<tmp 1>", line 9, in <module>
    st.tag('What is the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?'.split())
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 66, in tag
    return sum(self.tag_sents([tokens]), [])
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 89, in tag_sents
    stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 134, in java
    raise OSError('Java command failed : ' + str(cmd))
OSError: Java command failed : ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin/java.exe', '-mx1000m', '-cp', 'D:\\Downloads\\stanford-postagger-2015-04-20\\stanford-postagger-2015-04-20\\stanford-postagger.jar', 'edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger', '-model', 'D:\\Downloads\\stanford-postagger-2015-04-20\\stanford-postagger-2015-04-20\\models\\english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger', '-textFile', 'c:\\users\\wiki\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmp0ruajz', '-tokenize', 'false', '-outputFormatOptions', 'keepEmptySentences', '-encoding', 'utf8']
```

What should I do?

Comment: Try `java_path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_71\\bin\\java.exe"`

Comment: May I know where the code snippet is coming from? It's appearing in many places and maybe it's not giving the users the right information on how to use stanford API in NLTK. Your link to the documentation isn't correct in the post.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I still get the same error. and about the code snippet, I got it from the link that I've posted and mixed it with some other suggestions that was proposed here in stackoverflow to make the tagger work.

Comment: The link you've posted in wrong, it leads to the print-screen image, can you correct the link?

Comment: Ah but that's without the OS environ code. Did you get the `os.environ['JAVAHOME']` from somewhere or did you come up with it? Sorry for the "pester-like" question, we'll like to find out where it comes from and correct it.

Comment: Please see https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9